# Algorithm to find low/high atmospheric pressure systems in gridded raster data

Tags: raster, algorithm, weather

What's the commonly used algorithm for finding center positions and values of [low/high atmospheric pressure systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pressure_system) in gridded raster data (GRIB/NetCDF/GeoTIFF)?

First I tried a naive approach to iterate through the data array, and find points with smaller/larger value than all their neighbors. This gives surprisingly good results, however it also gives lots of false positives, especially near the equator. I need to filter the results somehow, but I'm out of ideas how. It seems there needs to be some tolerance setting.

[image: pressure]

I tried blurring the data, it helps, but still it is not perfect. Also, it often shifts the positions outside of the smallest contour, so it can be perceived as incorrect.

I already use [marching squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marching_squares) to find contours. A possible approach could be to chain the functions together, find min/max in every smallest closed contour.

However, I still feel that it should be possible somehow to implement separately from contours. Is there a way? Ideally in JS, but I welcome suggestions in any language or tool if it mentions which algorithm does it use, so that I can reimplement it in JS.

Comment: What results did the gradient descent give you? Because it may be a perfect candidate in such wavy landscape, especially if you decide to apply some [momentum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_gradient_descent). Data scientists call this guy the 'stochastic gradient descent' then. Just a thought...

Comment: I'm not familiar with it, do you have an example using it on a data array, please? What I found seems to apply on functions instead of static data array.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by false positives in your naive but sensible initial approach. I'm fascinated as to why this should occur. Any point that is smaller than or larger than all 8 of its pixel neighbors should be a local high or low. You would need to extend this logic if a local high or low was characterized by two or more adjacent identical values.

Comment: Examples of what I'd like to achieve: 2x L above Norway sea - as a user I'd expect just one L there. 3x H above Sweden - as a user I'd expect nothing there, because there is no closed contour. The area near equator - there are simply too many points to display, it's overcrowded. I think that the issues could be caused by the fact that comparing to the nearest pixels makes results to depend on the pixel resolution.

Comment: Also, currently there could be a missed local min/max if there are multiple neighboring min/max points with the same value. Basically a flat min/max area. This would not be detected with `<`/`>` comparison.  Using `<=`/`>=` instead would produce more points again.

Comment: You say your data is gridded but you are showing contours. Remember that these will be an over-simplification of the true situation. For example, concerning the 2x Low above Norway, have you checked that this contour contains just one true absolute low or is there in fact 2 that don't show because of the contour interval?

Comment: Concerning your next point, indeed, neighboring multiple identical points will not detect as a high or low unless you can modify your code to find any point that is >= the largest/smallest of the 8 neighbours. This would find the high or low but both/all the highest/lowest points would be identified and you would then have to clean this using a second logic to delete all but one of the adjoining points.

Comment: Thanks Leigh for your input. You’re right that the expected output depends on the contours, which are simplified already. I’m going to try to implement finding min/max in every smallest closed contour.