# MapServer: How to find all high and low spots in a raster?

Tags: raster, mapserver, weather, grib-2

I'm currently tinkering with MapServer to see if it could work as a backend for the remodel of my hobby stormchaser website.
Is it possible (in MapServer) to find **all** high and low spots in a raster grid and put a label on them. Obviously, I'm trying to make an atmospheric pressure map with "H" and "L" markers.
I know how to find **the** highest and the lowest value in a grid with GDAL but I basically want to find all points which are highest/lowest among all their neighbors.
A solution inside of MapServer would be preferred but I wouldn't be opposed to some preprocessing script.

Comment: I don't know Mapserver but you might like to check a similar question here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/386050/algorithm-to-find-low-high-atmospheric-pressure-systems-in-gridded-raster-data. Not answered fully though.

Comment: Thanks. I have seen that appears to be about doing it in Javascript, i.e. in the client while I am looking to render tiles server side with the information stamped on them.

Comment: You can try contouring the data ~ https://www.mapserver.org/input/vector/contour.html